# Lyckety-Splyt gets some Deli

Tags: rhyme, lateral-thinking, letters

This here's my song, G,
'Bout when I was hongry:

I went to the deli
In harlem. They sell me
A sandwich so smelly,
Thought I was in Delhi.

They put grits of hominy
On top of pastronimy.
Nine bucks? Are ya connin' me?
This @#%$@*& economy

And then this here fat-head
Ain't usin' no whitebread!
Be foldin' in flatbread
I shot his ass flat dead.
<sub>(drops mic)</sub>

`This is a   _ _ _   _ _ _  about a   _ _ _   _ _ _ _ .`

> **Looking for a single letter answer.**

Comment: Maybe should use @#$ for the last line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking for a single letter answer.

> w?

Because

> This is a rap about a 'w'rap? It's a W rap.

Comment: Using the spaces in the question, I was looking for Rot13("Guvf vf n  onq enc nobhg n  onq jenc.") Close enough! I'll mark this as accepted soon.